# Develop on a dev server remotely via Eclipse Che or some other editor

Tags: ubuntu, development-environment, cloud9-ide, web-development-server, eclipse-che

How to develop on a dev server remotely via Eclipse Che or some other editor? With terminal access.

Example: Cloude9, I tried it and it's great. I'm trying to do the same on my own server because that's where all my files and configurations are.

I'm programming in python and php.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can connect your own server to Cloud9 using [SSH workspaces](https://docs.c9.io/docs/running-your-own-ssh-workspace) and develop directly on it.

One thing to note, however, is that SSH workspaces are a premium feature.

[Full Disclosure: I work for Cloud9]

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking to host myself. I may have to use it for work server as well.